# Trying to click on an image area with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap CDN library building my website. (And I'm new to HTML in general)

I'm trying to use an Image as index page.
The Image contains 2 places where buttons should be:

[image: Image contains 2 places where buttons should be:]

I managed to determine and calculate the areas, but I can't make it work...

```
<div id= "wrap">
<div class="container" id = "c_1">


<img id="imag-main" src="pic/start.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="empty.html" shape="poly" coords="3379,2255,3380,2711,2422,2712,2425,2256" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="login.html" shape="poly" coords="3458,2256,4430,2255,4415,2711,3458,2711" />

</map>

</div>
</div>
```

any thoughts? all HTML files are in same file.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Is this going to be a responsive site? If so you'll need to do a little extra work to make your image map responsive.

Comment: yes, but for now I just want that both areas will go the href upon clicking on them

Comment: Have you considered using SVG (instead of an image) and wrapping the two buttons with an anchor? Something [along these lines](https://jsfiddle.net/xpwzewcz/)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SVG, will it be multi platform like bootstrap tools?

Comment: Yes, [SVG support](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg). Did you not create the image in your post? If you did, there should be an export to SVG option in the software you used to create it.

Comment: ok, ill try to ask the person who made this.  thanks, man

Answer (score 0):

You can place a div with that img as background-image and set 2 buttons/divs with position absolute.

Like this:

```css
.home {
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

.btn1 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:30%;
}

.btn2 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <a class="btn1" href="#">
    page one
  </a>
   <a class="btn2" href="#">
    page two
  </a>
</div>
```